# JavaScript Regex replace string between 2 comment tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to replace strings between two comment like this:

`<span>Just <!--{-->250<!--}--> characters available!</span>`

I would like to replace `250` with another number.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
text.replace(/(<!--\{-->)(\d+)(<!--\}-->)/, '$1replaced$3'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the exact javascript syntax, but the following should match on just the number (that's what you want, right? You just want to replace the "250"?)

```
(?<=<!\-\-\{\-\->)\d+(?=<\!\-\-\}\-\->)
```